# React: How to pass data to children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React and what I am doing might not make sense.
What I am trying to do is just to pass a data to from a parent component which is used in every screen to children.

My code is like this.

`AppDrawer.tsx`

```
const AppDrawer: React: FC<Props> = ({
    children,
  }) => {
    const [aString, setString] = React.useState<string>('Hello');
...

<div>
  <Drawer>
    ...
  </Drawer/>
  <main>
    <div>
      <Container>
        {children}
      </Container>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

`App.tsx`

```
<Swith>
    <AppDrawer>
        <Route path="/" component={ChildCompoent} />
        ...
        ...
    </AppDrawer>
</Switch>
```

`ChildComponent.tsx`

```
export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    ..
  }
}
```

And now I want to access `aString` in `AppDrawer.tsx` in child components but I couldn't figure out how I can do it.  How can I do it?

Comment: You need to use Context API (check docs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use Context here. Context allows you to pass down something from the parent component, and you can get it at the child component (no matter how deep it is) if you'd like.

I made an example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/passing-down-data-k4os7?file=/src/App.tsx)

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

Updated: I notice you use Route, Router, and I don't use in my codesandbox. However, it's fine though. The main idea is to use context :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's helpful but seems like I have to define a type of the method to update a state.

Answer (score 1):

Use render in component Route

```
<Route
  path='/'
  render={(props) => (
    <ChildCompoent {...props}/>
  )}
/>
```

And should not props aString in component AppDrawer

Comment: Sorry can you show me more details? How can I pass the props from parent and access from child?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the version of react and if it is still supported but this how I did this in my app.
try checking for React. Children over here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren
see if it's suitable for your case.

```js
    render() {
        const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                ...child.props,
                setHasChangesBeenMade: (nextValue) => this.setState({ hasChangesBeenMade: nextValue })
            });
        });

        return (children[0]);
    }
```

for you it should be something like this :

```js
const AppDrawer: React: FC<Props> = ({
    children,
  }) => {
    const [aString, setString] = React.useState<string>('Hello');
...

        const childrens = React.Children.map(children, child => {
            return React.cloneElement(child, {
                ...child.props,
                aString: aString
            });
        });
<div>
  <Drawer>
    ...
  </Drawer/>
  <main>
    <div>
      <Container>
        {childrens[0]}
      </Container>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```